# Alert not triggered in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have this alert in prometheus:

```
- alert: Error_pods
expr: sum by (namespace) (kube_pod_status_ready{namespace="gradl-enterprise", condition="false"}) > 0
for: 5m
```

And I can see the data is being returned with the query for this period of time:

[image]

My problem is this alert continues in the *Normal* state and does not trigger. Does anyone see something that I'm missing?

EDIT1: Just to provide more context, I've tried this one also with no success

```
- alert: Error_pods
expr: sum by (namespace) (kube_pod_status_ready{namespace="gradl-enterprise", condition="false"}) > bool 0
for: 5m
```

Comment: Can you see this alert in list of rules shown in prometheus' web console? Also, can you check if this is symple formatting error (on the side of the question) that you are missing spaces in second and third lines of the rule?

Comment: Hey @markalex! Thanks! Yes, I can see in grafana, the image above comes from the alert section of the grafana web app. As the rule is being showed in grafana and the query returns data for the alert I've disregarded formatting errors.